# Creating a search form with order by fields composed of model properties and related pivot count

Tags: php, laravel, search, pivot

I'm trying to create a search form for my Laravel app. Basically a user can enter some fields (searchable model related, like the title) and sort it in different ways; title, create date, but also vote count or favorite count. The last two are results from a pivot table (many to many relations).

I've been struggling with this but I don't know how to proceed. Here's what I have so far:

```
public function search(SearchRequest $request)
{
    $posts = Post::where('published', 1);

    if (strlen($request->title) > 0) {
        $posts->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->title . '%');
    }

    switch($request->order_by) {
        case 'title' : $orderBy = 'title'; break;
        case 'createDate' : $orderBy = 'created_at'; break;
        case 'favorites' : $orderBy = 'post_favorites.count(*)'; break;
        case 'votes' : $orderBy = 'post_votes.count(*)'; break;
    }

    $posts->orderBy($orderBy, $request->order_by_direction);
    $posts = $posts->get();

    var_dump($posts);
}
```

To keep it simple I've rewritten the code to a typical blog post example. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: to get a little more details, in your example above your only searching by title, but displaying the results dependant on 4 options the has chosen? But if not title just return all the published posts by the users oder request? if not then yout coudl surround it all in the if etc, ?

Comment: It's a little difficult to know what you are trying to proceed with.  Could you please clarify what you are looking for exactly or where the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

going to take a stab on it, but its not tested as got nothing to test it on etc, so bear with me, other might take it further simpler, but hope it helps.

```
public function search(SearchRequest $request)
{

    if(count($request->get('title')) > 0){
        $search_text = $request->get('title');
        $order_by = $request->get('order_by');
        $display_by = $request->get('order_by_direction');

        $search_results = Post::where('title', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%')->get();

        if($display_by == 'asc') return this::orderSearchResults($search_results, $order_by);

        return this::orderSearchResults($search_results, $order_by)->reverse();

    } else {
        //do something else here
    }
}

private function orderSearchResults($search_results, $order_by)
{
        switch ($order_by) {
            case 'title' :
                return $search_results->sortby('title');
                break;
            case 'createDate' :
                return $search_results->sortby('created_at');
                break;
            case 'favorites' :
                return $search_results->sortby(function($search){
                    return count($search['post_favorites']);
                });
                break;
            case 'votes' :
                return $search_results->sortby(function($search){
                    return count($search['post_votes']);
                });
                break;
            default :
                return $search_results;
                break;
        }
}
```

the second part is based on the resulted being returned as a collection etc.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a try tomorrow! Thanks Simon! +1 for the effort

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation where I had to get users with search option on different fields (search in name, email, phone... etc) and order them by number of posts or name or email... and this worked as intended. I tried to rewrite the code to match the example you have provided.

```
 // if the user didn't fill the field, we assign default values
  $searchText = $request->input('searchText') ?: null; // the terms we are looking for
  $targetField = $request->input('targetField') ?: 'title'; // in which field we want to search
  $orderBy = $request->input('orderBy') ?: 'id'; // field used to order the results
  $order = $request->input('order') ?: 'DESC'; // order direction

  // from here we start assembling our query depending on the request
  $query = DB::table('posts')->select('*')->where('published', 1);

  // if the user typed something in search bar, we look for those terms
  $query->when($searchText, function($query) use ($searchText,$targetField) {
    return $query->where($targetField,'like','%'.$searchText.'%');
  });

  // if the user wants to order by votes
  $query->when($orderBy === 'votes', function ($query) use ($order) {
    return $query->addSelect(DB::raw('(select count(post_id) from post_votes where post_votes.post_id = posts.id) AS nbvotes'))
                 ->orderBy('nbvotes',$order));
  });
  // apply same logic for favorites

  // if the orderBy is neither favorites or votes, by name or email for example...
  $query->when($orderBy != 'favorites' && $orderBy != 'votes', function ($query) use ($orderBy,$order) {
    return $query->orderBy($orderBy,$order);
  });

  // executing the query
  $posts = $query->get();
```